# How to know the nominal resolution of an image to use as an asset in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image-resolution

I have some photos of different sizes for different android and iOS devices. Like, a photo in 800x1280 resolution and in 540x960.

Flutter Docs say that if I place those photos in a proper way, Flutter will use the best suiting one to my device as an asset. But how should I place them? Which resolution is 1.0x, which one is 2.0x and so on?

The related part of Flutter Docs is here:

[Declaring resolution-aware image assets - flutter.io](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#declaring-resolution-aware-image-assets)

Comment: Is this video any help as it explains device independent pixels?   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0rfDeaxehc